# Struct with another struct inside of it using ctypes

Tags: python, c, data-structures, ctypes

I am developing a ratchet control software, it uses a dll called `xpcomlib`, and has examples of use in C. I am developing in Python and for the use of the DLL I am using `ctypes`, I was able to do as eg the same needs from one pointeiro to one structure and one structure has another. Let's make it clearer.

Here's a part of the manual:

```cpp
int FAR PASCAL FXPBasicConvFromText(
  const char FAR* szFileOrig, // Source File name will be converted
  const char FAR* szFileDest, // Dest file name will be converted
  CONVFILEFORMAT FAR* pF // Pointer to source file format
);
```

The `pF` argument is a pointer to a structure of type `CONVFILEFORMAT` that defines the format of the source file. `cFields` Number of fields in the source file, must be between 1 and 10. For each of the `cFields` fields above we have the `Field` structure defined by:

`CONVFILEFORMAT`

```cpp
struct {
   cName [11]     Field name only for conversions with destination file type DBF
   cType          Field type XPFLD_INT, XPFLD_FLO, XPFLD_STR. See XPCOMxx.H.
   cLength        Length of field
   cDec           Number of decimal places used for floating point in file conversion
XPbasic format for DBASE format
} Field [10];
```

Example made in the manual:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include “xpcom16.h”

char szInFile[20];
char szOutFile[20];
CONVFILEFORMAT fF;

int PASCAL WinMain(HANDLE hInstance, HANDLE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    fF.cFields = 3;
    fF.Field[0].cType = XPFLD_STR;
    fF.Field[0].cLength = 80;
    fF.Field[0].cDec = 0;
    fF.Field[1].cType = XPFLD_INT;
    fF.Field[1].cLength = 2;
    fF.Field[1].cDec = 0;
    fF.Field[2].cType = XPFLD_FLO;
    fF.Field[2].cLength = 8;
    fF.Field[2].cDec = 0;
    strcpy(szInFile, “C:\\TRIX\\ARQTXT.DAT”);
    strcpy(szOutFile, “C:\\TRIX\\ARQXPB.DAT”);
    if (FXPBasicConvFromText(szInFile, szOutFile, &fF))
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Given this, I need to make use of the dll in python, so far I have done this:

```python
class ConvFileField(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cName", ctypes.c_char_p), ("cType", ctypes.c_byte),
                ("cLength", ctypes.c_byte), ("cDec", ctypes.c_byte)]

class Struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cFields", ctypes.c_byte), ("Field", ctypes.POINTER(ConvFileField))]

    elems = (ConvFileField * 10)()
    Field = ctypes.cast(elems, ctypes.POINTER(ConvFileField))

formatPointer = ctypes.POINTER(Struct)
formatPointer.cFields = 0 #Works
formatPointer.Field[0].cType = 1 #Doesn't work
```

However I get the following error saying that my structure does not contain the `Field` field, with the above `cFields` working normal.

```
formatPointer.Field[0].cType = 1 AttributeError: type object
'LP_Struct' has no attribute 'Field'
```

Comment: Show us the CONVFILEFORMAT struct definition.

Comment: It's there I will write it wait a moment

Comment: It's ready,  I put a text above the struct, take a look please

Comment: That is, at best, a fragment of the definition. Please post the entire CONVFILEFORMAT struct definition.

Comment: In the manual there is just it

Comment: It looks like this library is almost exclusively used in Brazil. Everything I can find about it online is on .br websites, in Portuguese. I was hoping to find online documentation, but all I've found are forum posts.

Comment: *CONVFILEFORMAT* structure definition is not present. You only added some pseudo-code / description. Please add its definition from a *.h* file. Same thing for struct *Field*. `class Struct` should be `class Field`. Aggregation is *FXPBasicConvFromText* -> *CONVFILEFORMAT* -> *Field (apparently unnamed?)*. The *Python* code shows confusion.

Comment: So apparently this involves communication with some *Trix technologia* piece of hardware. Didn't it come with an *SDK* (next to the manual) ? There you might be able to find the *.h* files that contain the structures definitions.

Answer (score 0):

With only a mangled, partial definition of a single field of CONVFILEFORMAT, I cannot tell you exactly how to define the same struct type in ctypes. I can, however, answer the general question of how to handle struct types with nested structs, arrays, and arrays of structs.

A struct field of the form

```
struct {
    ...
} Field [10];
```

is an *array*, not a pointer. Specifically, it is a field named `Field`, whose type is a length-10 array of an anonymous struct type defined by the preceding `struct {...}` part. If your ctypes code defines the type of the elements of `Field` as `ConvFileField`, then the correct declaration of the `Field` field itself would be

```
('Field', ConvFileField*10)
```

in the `_fields_` list. If your `_fields_` list is otherwise correct (we can't tell), then the correct declaration would be

```
class CONVFILEFORMAT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('cFields', ctypes.c_byte), ('Field', ConvFileField*10)]
```

Incidentally, your `cName` field in `ConvFileField` has the same issue. `cName` appears to be a length-11 array in the actual C, but you've declared a pointer instead.